# Forms in HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I self learning HTML and CSS and have to got to the bit about email forms, so I have got a working form (without using php), but the only problem is it looks awful and i don't have any clue on how to edit it

```
<p>
<label for="myemail">Your e-mail:<span id="star">*</span></label>
<input type="email" name="myemail" id="myemail" value="type your email..." maxlength="40" size="20" required="required" onclick="this.value=''" /><br>
<label for="fullmane">Your full name:<span id="star">*</span></label>
<input type="fullname" name="name" id="fullname" value="Please enter your full name.." maxlength="40" size="20" required="required" onclick="this.value=''"/>
<br>
<label for="emailcontent">Comments:</label>
<div id="email">
<input type="emailcontent" name="emailcontent" id="emailcontent" value="Please enter your question..." maxlength="20" size="20" required="required" />
</div>
```

Okay so this is giving the basic look for a form and there are a couple of things I would like to change:
1) The size of the emailcontent box, I have done this in a CSS file but it still only writes in the middle of the box in a single line,
2) have it so when typing it automatically starts a new line instead of just stopping.
3) change the look of the buttons (will i need Javascript?)
4) have it open in a separate window, after clicking on a click on the previous page

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: *I have done this in a CSS file...*: then add the relevant css  as well, in the question.

Comment: there's literally thousands of examples&tutorials of forms on the web [here's](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/building-forms/) just one such example. [here's one for opening a popup](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_popup_window_code.cfm). Please at least try researching before posting

Comment: Consider google as your best friend. You will get everything on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to style your buttons like this :-

```
input[type=fullname] 
 { 
   padding:5px; border:2px solid #ccc; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
 }

input[type=text]:focus {border-color:#333; }

input[type=email] 
{
  padding:5px 15px; 
  background:#ccc; 
  border:0 none;
  cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
}
```